# What Amazon EC2 machine state does a stop hook in juju correspond to?

Tags: juju

There are 2 parts to the question

1. Does the destroy-service command results in the stop hook being called for Juju?
2. In case of Amazon EC2 machine instances what state (Terminate or Stop) are they put into when the stop hook completes its execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `juju destroy-service` *should* call the service's `stop` hook, but doesn't.  It's a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/872264
2. The state that the corresponding machine is left in is provider-specific... for EC2, the machine is cleaned up (remove charm) and set to be re-used by juju for another service or service unit.  As such, the EC2 state of `running` is not changed.  For LXC, `destroy-service` removes the associated container entirely (without calling `stop` first!).

Comment: Does that mean that if we want to stop the running machines in EC2 we have to so externally - I mean issue a command using EC2 API or use its web console? That juju doesnot support anything equivalent?

Comment: Since Juju provisioned these machines wouldn't it be advisable that  there should be an option to terminate/stop the same, with a different command than environment-destroy. I believe that would immensely improve Juju's capability as a provisioning service

Comment: I am willing to raise this as a bug or/and work on the juju source to achieve the same. However a spec consensus is reqd before I can release into the juju trunk